How to mask resolver name from requestor in service now itsm
I have the use case where the requestor shouldn't not know who is resolving the ticket. The workgroup being exposed is ok. Even an alias is fine but name should not be visible. Is it possible in service now?
Tried things but global restrictions are not feasible.

would it just be a case of configuring a read Access Control record to restrict the reading of this field unless..... ?
